# Flutter Play Store Warning : play-services-safetynet 2022

Tags: flutter, google-play

The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline)

Cannot find in youtube...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same issues for my project. I'm used React Native. My best options is exclude play-services-safetynet.

Add below script to exclude play-services-safetynet in file android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

And please make sure file android/build.gradle use

```
classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13')
```

Already try that script and success to Release My App without get Critical issues

Commands to check your project dependency in Android Studio terminal :

```
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

you can search text 'play-services-safetynet' is gone in you project dependency. After that, upload your release bundle to Google Play Console. Cheers... :-)

Comment: Yes.. it removes "safetynet" from dependency list. But when verify phone number ( which is a function from firebase_auth" ) the app is getting crash. Any solution ?